# I keep finding random screenshots in the Pictures folder

Tags: screenshot, folder

As the title says, the random screenshots are placed in the Pictures folder, and not in Pictures/Screenshots/ where the screenshots I take are saved.
Checked the internet before posting this, couldn't find much. And no, the print screen button on the keyboard is not stuck.

I'm on elementary os Loki 0.4.1, latest version, freshly installed a few days ago on a clean hdd.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Just for the heck of it, have you checked that if other keyboard shortcuts for screenshots are being executed in error as you are trying to execute other shortcuts?

Comment: Yes I checked, no such shortcuts. When I was at the computer a screenshot was automatically taken. I could tell this, because RedShift app stopped for 1 second. Then I checked the Pictures folder an there was the screenshot.

Comment: I've spent a fair amount of time on Linux-based forums and this is the first time I've heard of this. I'm really hoping we can get to the bottom of it! Next question(s): What day did you install? Has this been happening out of the gate with the install? Have you applied updates since the install?

Comment: I think the problem could be the cheap ass brand new keyboard I bought. I pressed the print screen button a couple of times, and today I had no 'auto' screenshots. I'll check again in a few days with my old keyboard. Thanks Tim for the intersest in this post!]

Comment: Please remember to comment back as to the outcome of tying your old keyboard. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Tim for you replys. It was actually the faulty keyboard that was taking screenshots :-/

Comment: Hey hihi! Glad to hear you worked it out! Sometimes "new" doesn't equate to "quality" I guess. Just an FYI, I generally use Logitech devices as a rule and have not run into any issues other than a mouse I had a few years ago but I was able to ultimately solve the compatibility issue. Good Luck and enjoy eOS!